# Grep rows where change occurs in columns

Tags: grep

I'm wondering if there is a grep command to return the row lines where a character in a column changes... for example if I have a file:

```
1 1010
1 101010
1 10101010
2 1010
2 101010
2 10101010
```

And I wanted to see just the lines were the increase in column 1 occurs, so:

```
1 10101010
2 1010
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: do I sense correctly this is a homework problem?

Comment: nope! i've got a 26 million line file and i'm trying to suss out any natural break points without actually subsetting the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk you can do:

```
awk 'x && $1!=x {print y; print}; {x=$1; y=$0}'
```